# How to return an Int type with DataStore

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, datastore

How to return an Int type with DataStore

```
class StoreScore(private val context: Context) {

    companion object {
        private val Context.dataStoree: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore("userScore")
        val USER_SCORE = intPreferencesKey("my_number")
    }

    val getScore: Flow<Int?> = context.dataStoree.data.map { preferences ->
        preferences[USER_SCORE] ?: 1
    }

    suspend fun increaseScore(tun: Int) {
        context.dataStoree.edit { preferences ->
            val currentCounterValue = preferences[USER_SCORE] ?: 1
            preferences[USER_SCORE] = currentCounterValue + tun
        }
    }
}
```

But this returns the following in the Composable

```
val userScore: State<{Comparable<*>? & java.io.Serializable?}>
```

And I don't know how to return a "val userScore: Int", I can't use "userScore.value as Int" or "toInt()", since it is still a Flow type.

Comment: How about `val userScore: State<Int?> = storeScore.getScore.collectAsState(initial = null)` or `collectAsStateWithLifecycle(initial = null)`?